# Iterating through NSDictionary creating new NSDictionary with changed values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I have a NSDictionary created from JSON:

```
bookDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: bookData
                 options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                 error: &anError];
```

each book has many assets and each asset has a layer. There are a maximum of 3 layers.
An asset can have a type of text or image.

I am trying to accomplish two things. Firstly create 3 new dictionaries, layer1, layer2 and layer3, and populate them with the assets for each layer.

And for each image asset I want to download and save the image for later use, this is the code I am using to save image:

```
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL/%@",[assetData objectForKey:@"content" ]];
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSArray   *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"filename.png"];
[urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

and for each Image asset after they have been saved locally I need to replace the url with the filePath.

Suggestions would be very helpful, and if anyone has sample code of similar manipulations to NSDictionaries would be great

Sample data from the JSON request:

```
"average rating":"4",
"# of ratings":"41",
"list price":"43.99",
"your price":"43.15",
"thumburl":"/img/avatar.png",
"assets":[
            {
        "id":"8",
        "type":"Text",
        "content":"T-Bar%20Controller",
        "layer":"layer-1",
        "top":"190",
        "left":"74",
        "width":"130",
        "height":"28",
        "action":"",
        "url":""
     },
             {
        "id":"9",
        "type":"Text",
        "content":"Scroller",
        "layer":"layer-1",
        "top":"304",
        "left":"804",
        "width":"118",
        "height":"27",
        "action":"",
        "url":""
     },
            "id":"63",
        "type":"Image",
        "content":"ugc/ronny/25/assets/pho.JPG",
        "layer":"layer-2",
        "top":"0",
        "left":"0",
        "width":"340",
        "height":"191",
        "action":"",
        "url":""}
```

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: If we had a clue what the structure of the data is it would help immensely.  Can you show a sample (about 2 books' worth) of the JSON?

Comment: Sorry I left the sample data out. I have updated my question.

Comment: It's not at all clear what a "layer" is or how you want to organize things based on that.  Do you mean that each of these entities (whatever the outer level is called) should have 3 dictionaries, for 3 layers, or do you mean there should b 3 dictionaries overall that hold the layers for all of your entities.  Hint:  Draw what you want, in schematic form, with boxes and arrows, then figure out what dictionary/array structure matches that.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. In the example data above I have 3 "Assets", two assets have the value "layer-1" and one asset has the value "layer-2". The result I am looking to achieve with this sample data is two new dictionaries, one with the two assets that have the value "layer-1" and the second dictionary with the asset that has the value "layer-2".

Comment: And those dictionaries just stand alone?  What do you do with the assets for the next entity?

Comment: Each time I only have one "bookDictionary" which is overridden by each json request

Comment: So what you're asking is "How do I find the assets array, loop through it, and insert each asset in a different dictionary, based on the value of `layer` in the asset?"?

Comment: that is exactly what I am trying to do. and in addition for assets that are of type "Image" I want to save the image locally and replace the remote url with the local path. For example in the sample data above, the last asset is an image, and the "content" field holds the url to the image. This value needs to be changed to the local path after the image has been downloaded.